# Executing line commands arguments with 2 variables problem c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to open my .exe "application" with 2 arguments. When I write the command line myself without `" "` it don't want to work. When I write the command line using `"C:/Path" "A" "B"` it does work.

How do I fix this?

```
if(element.SaveType == "1")
{
    DirectoryInfo srcDir = new DirectoryInfo((string)element.SourcePath);
    DirectoryInfo dstDir = new DirectoryInfo((string)element.DestinationPath);
    if (element.didEncrypt == true)
    {
        if (Directory.GetFiles(srcDir.FullName, ((string)element.EncryptExt)).Length == 0)
        {
            string pat = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Client Fractal\source\repos\CryptoSoft\CryptoSoft\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\CryptoSoft.exe");
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = pat;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = srcDir.FullName + dstDir.FullName; // source / target;
            Console.WriteLine(p.StartInfo.Arguments);
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: [...spaces are interpreted as a separator between multiple arguments. A single argument that includes spaces must be surrounded by quotation marks,  but those quotation marks are not carried through to the target application. To include quotation marks in the final parsed argument, triple-escape each mark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: In addition, why are you using `Path.Combine()` with only one argument?

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments are space-character delimited, so you'd need to insert a space character or your arguments will end up getting squashed together.

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = srcDir.FullName + " " + dstDir.FullName;
```

But of course, if either `srcDir.FullName` or `dstDir.FullName` contain space characters of their own (and `FullName` suggests they do), you will need to surround them with double quote characters.

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" srcDir.FullName + "\" \"" + dstDir.FullName + "\"";
```